# Creating a variable that can be compared across processes

Tags: python, process, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have code like the following,

```
class _Process(multiprocessing.Process):

    STOP = multiprocessing.Manager().Event()

    def __init__(self, queue, process_fn):

        self._q = queue
        self._p = process_fn
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):

        while True:
            dat = self._q.get()
            if not dat is _Process.STOP:
                self._p(dat, self._q)
                self._q.task_done()
            else:
                self._q.task_done()
                break
```

but, I cannot compare `STOP` successfully. This isn't that surprising when I'm using `is` since, I believe, `is` compares object id's and from the docs *" ... This is the address of the object in memory."* So, since I'm using multiple processes the memory address will be different. (I can't compare it with `==` either though, and I'm not sure why this is).

This happens with any object I create with `Manager()`, but if I use a "true" singleton (`True` or `False` or `None`) it does work. Although that's not an appropriate solution since any of those values may be valid in the queue.

So how can I create a variable, like the singletons, that can be compared across processes?

(N.B. I have tried using a dedicated class too, but get errors about it not being able to be pickled.)

**Update:** The answer does seem to be to use a class, but I was receiving the pickleing problems as I was only trying with an inner class. Moving it to module scope fixed the error and it works fine. - Thanks @Schnouki!

---

Here's an example (and pointless) usage of the code, that shows the error ...

```
def f(data, queue):
    print(data)

q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

for i in range(4):
    p = _Process(q, f)
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    q.put(i)

q.join()

for i in range(4):
    q.put(_Process.STOP)

q.join()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a weird way to use an `Event` object... If you can't use `None` or a boolean, I suggest you use a dedicated class and test the type of what you get from the queue:

```
class StopProcessing(object):
    pass

#...

q.put(StopProcessing())

#...

while True:
    dat = self._q.get()
    if type(dat) is StopProcessing:
        # ...
```

Or, of course, you could just keep using the `multiprocessing.Event` and test for its type. However this would probably be quite misleading for someone else reading your code; using a dedicated type seems much cleaner and Pythonic to me.

**EDIT:** Ok, so apparently this doesn't work because the new class is not picklable. So here's another idea: what if you directly put the type inside your queue, like this:

```
class StopProcessing(object):
    pass
#...
q.put(StopProcessing)
#...
while True:
    dat = self._q.get()
    if dat is StopProcessing:
        #...
```

According to the [pickle doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), "classes that are defined at the top level of a module" can be pickled.

Comment: Thanks, I just used `Event` as an example. Like I say it happens with any of the objects returned by `Manager`, I would probably just use `Value` at the end of the day if it worked (not really sure why I didn't in the example!). Thanks for the suggestion about using a class, I should have mentioned, I have already tried that and get an error about the class not being able to be pickled. I've updated the question to mention this.

Comment: What if you directly put the *type* inside your queue, e.g. `q.put(StopProcessing)`, and then test it with `if dat is StopProcessing`? According to the [pickle doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), "classes that are defined at the top level of a module" can be pickled.

Comment: Ah! I had tried it by adding just the type, yes. In fact this was the first thing I tried, before messing around with `Manager` objects, but I always had the class as an inner class. Taking it into module scope makes it work perfectly. Thankyou very much. I wonder if you could add that tip to your answer to match my update in the question.